# PDF files starts with "LS0tl" base 64 string cannot be opened on pdf.js browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js to display pdf files in the browser. Content of pdf file is a base64 string.

If base64 string starts with "LS0tl" pdf.js cannot open it, but never had a problem with "JVBER". When I download pdf files, both files open without a problem.

Comment: Anything that starts from LS0tl ('---') is not a valid PDF file per PDF32000 spec. Try to properly report that at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues -- they might be able to add this feature for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @async5 . Do you have an idea about how desktop applications like Adobe or Nuance can open these files when files are downloaded?

Comment: oozken, I think you need to ask Adobe about why choose to open files that don't conform their specification. But anyway see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#corrupted-pdf